# Center image in DIV and hide the overflowing

Tags: css

This is kind of an unique case. I am trying to achieve the following:

1. Square images should be 100% 100%. Basically fill out the entire DIV (which is squared)
2. All images should fill out the entire height of the DIV.
3. All images should be aligned center
4. If they overflow the X-axis, they should overflow and hide

https://jsfiddle.net/cxnyLxfn/2/

```
.image-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.image-container img {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I almost achieved this, except for centering the images no matter what. The Google logo should be centered and the rest look fine as they are. How do I achieve my four requirements?

Comment: unless your'e writing in Sass nesting is not a good idea as far as i know

Comment: @ImmortalDude I just added Sass to my styles. I'll change it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually use a flex approach to this:

```css
.image-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/modules/logos_page/GitHub-Mark.png" />
</div>
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--pEKSmwzm--/c_scale,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/1414228815325188681.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="http://www.zevendesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/google-logo-progress-270x480.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/31/12/56/google-1015752_960_720.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

put css for img

```
img {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
img {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Seems like that does it. Thanks! Never truly understood `transform: translate()`. Basically centers it 100% no matter what, right?

Comment: Yeah, whatever the size of the div or the screen, it should center the image

Answer (score 2):

Using [object fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) property...

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/6eL6qtry/4/)

```css
.image-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
}

img {
  object-fit: contain;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/modules/logos_page/GitHub-Mark.png" />
</div>
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--pEKSmwzm--/c_scale,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/1414228815325188681.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="http://www.zevendesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/google-logo-progress-270x480.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/31/12/56/google-1015752_960_720.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it is unsupported by IE and Edge.

Comment: I don't follow... I confirmed what you said. Regardless, it is still a property that solves the issue you are having.

Comment: Yes, which is supported in a few browsers. IE and Edge still takes up a lot of the browsers.

Answer (score 1):

The `tansform:translate()` will do the magic. Here is an working example-

```css
.image-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/modules/logos_page/GitHub-Mark.png" />
</div>
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--pEKSmwzm--/c_scale,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/1414228815325188681.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="http://www.zevendesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/google-logo-progress-270x480.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/31/12/56/google-1015752_960_720.png" />
</div>
```